# window.print() doesn't show updated div

Tags: jquery, html, printing, hidden

This post obviously wasn't well presented but rather than delete and re-post, I've edited it to try to make it clearer.

Putting it simply, there are a number of elements on my page where I want to be able to print content only within a particular div where all other divs are hidden. I found a post that describes defining a style as per below:

```
<style>
    @media print {
        body.printing * { display: none; }
        body.printing #print-me { display: block; }
    }

    @media screen {
        #print-me { display: none; }
    }  
</style>
```

In the body I have a div as below:

```
<div id='print-me'>
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
</div>
```

When the document has loaded, I'm trying to change the content in the print-me div to something else as per below, and using information kindly provided by eddie who responded to this post. The printing class is added to hide all other elements from the body of the document with the print-me div now set to display in a print window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass("printing");
  document.getElementById('print-me').innerHTML = '<p>crikey</p>';

  var htmlText = '<p>HTML TO PRINT</p>';

     $( "#print-me" ).html( htmlText ).promise().done(function() {
            window.print();
    });
});
```

However, if you view the Plunker example at the below link

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wz8IWx2xgcP6dqnoUtlL?p=preview)

you'll see that the print window opens up and the text that I'm setting the print-me div to doesn't display. The code in question looks as per below:

```
  $("body").addClass("printing");

  var htmlText = '<p>HTML TO PRINT</p>';

     $( "#print-me" ).html( htmlText ).promise().done(function() {
            window.print();
    });
```

if I change that to:

```
  $("body").addClass("printing");

  var htmlText = '<p>HTML TO PRINT</p>';

     $( "#print-me" ).text( htmlText ).promise().done(function() {
            window.print();
    });
```

then that does update the print-me div and displays in the print window. However, the htmlText displays literally and not as html.

Why does the former not display whereas the latter does, albeit as plain text.

I hope this better explains the problem, thank you for any help/suggestions on what is going on and how to solve the problem and/or how to improve the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on me.

HTML

```
<div id='print-section'></div>
<div id='print-btn'></div>
```

CSS: On print, you should set all as `hidden` except for the print `div` on print

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    @page {size: portrait}

    #print-section {
        visibility: visible;
        width : 100%;
        height : auto;
    }
}
```

JS: On the button, you should wait for the html to fully added the dynamic content and call `window.print();`

```
$("#print-btn").click(function(){
     var htmlText = '<p>HTML TO PRINT</p>';

     $( "#print-section" ).html( htmlText ).promise().done(function() {
            window.print();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I've updated the plunker sample as I'd left out a style definition. The print-me div is hidden from screen but meant to be set to visible when printing, with all other elements in the body hidden but this still doesn't work. I thought perhaps your statement that "wait for the html to fully added the dynamic content" was a clue but changing the code to using promise still doesn't show the print-me text in the print window. I've edited the post to reflect the change and added some additional information. Thanks heaps

Comment: You have to add `visibility: visible;` on your div in `@media print` like on my example

Comment: Thanks Eddie but isn't that what media print and media screen specify in the style declaration with $("body").addClass("printing"); which sets #print-me to display: block. Also, because it displays the changes if I set $('#print-me').text but not if I set $('#print-me').html, I don't see how it's to do with the visibility? If you check out the plunker link above, you'll see what I mean. Thanks heaps

Comment: This doesn't really do what I want it to do nor does it really explain my question but I've changed tack so as yours is the only response, you have my thanks and my vote